# Rails 3: client_side_validations gem; How do you add a custom message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, client-side-validation

I'm using bcardarella's client side validations gem (also a little new to ROR) and I'm having a problem figuring out how to change the error message displayed. Currently if a field is left blank, such as username, it displays the message "can't be blank". How can I add custom message?

I've seen that in your user model if you add a :with format validation, you can then create put a custom message by adding :message.

```
 :with => /^(?:\b\w+\b[\s\r\n]*){1,100}$/, :message => "is not formatted properly"
```

However, I do not need the :with formatting, I just want to customize the message of a current validation such as :presence. For example, simply instead of the message "can't be blank", I'd like the message to be "username can't be blank". But if you add :message without :with, you get errors.

Is there a simple work around, or something I'm missing here? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need to add the field name to the message.

In standard Rails validations the name of the field being validated is prepended to the message so when you validate `username` the message becomes "username can't be blank". These messages are usually displayed when the page reloads and they're all shown together at the top of the form.

However the Client_Side_Validations gem displays the errors next to the field they apply to so you would see something like:

Username: [______________] can't be blank

In this case there isn't any need to add the field name since the error is in-situ.